# how to change the color of holiday days in the DateTimepicker DevExpress component?

Tags: c#, calendar, devexpress, datetimepicker

I write an application using the DevExpress WinForms library. I wonder how to change the color of holiday days in the DateTimepicker component.

Comment: Hi -- what have you tried?

Comment: Hey. actually it's DateTimePicker WinForms Component. I was looking after I added this post, and I found only posts that it is impossible to change the color of individual dates.

Comment: Have you considered using the DevExpress DateEdit control instead? It will allow you to custom color/draw individual date cells allowing you to distinguish holidays.

Comment: Hey Brendon. Thank's for your answe! But i can't change i to the DateEdit control. But I will use it in Future :)